# OAuthException code #2 for particular account when using SessionLoginSample

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-oauth

We've run into a very strange case in which a particular Facebook account fails on a request to 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=XXX' after successful login.  After discovering this case in our app I verified that the exact same exception occurs when using the Facebook SDK sample - SessionLoginSample.  After successfully logging into this particular account and granting privileges I return to the sample app and click the test link.  This is the response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2
   }
}
```

When I log in using any other Facebook account I get what I would expect - JSON content that lists my facebook friends.

Any ideas on how to investigate this?  Haven't had much luck on the FB support site and it's not even clear to me how to post a bug report to them.

Comment: Are both accounts regular user accounts with friends, and are both using an app with no restrictions (e.g. being in sandbox mode?)

Comment: Both accounts are regular user accounts.  The account that fails was set up as a test account a few years ago and has one friend.  The app that I'm using to test is the Facebook SDK sample app - SessionLoginSample.  As far as I can tell, looking at the app settings from the account that works vs. doesn't work the settings look the same.

Comment: So one of them was a user that was converted to a 'platform test user' under the old, pre 2011 system for test users? I'd recommend not using that one any longer (assuming that's the one that's failing) because that functionality isn't supported anymore

Comment: Interesting, I meant we just created the account for testing.  Do you know how I could check to see if this user is considered a test user to fb?

Comment: Ah ha!  I see in the user's info that it's a part of the 'Facebook Platform Developer Test Accounts' group.  You suspect this is the issue?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments above, i think your problem is that one of the users is an old 'platform test user' from the old test user system - this may not work anymore.

The current test user framework is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ - these may be a good workaround if you can't use your real account for testing