# Facebook API OAuthException code 2 creating ads group

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am facing this less documented error when creating ads group using the FB api. 
 It asks the user to try again later, but I have been trying for the past 18 hours.

The error says: 
    {"error":{"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","type":"OAuthException","code":2}

Here are the curl commands ( I took the exact example from this doc page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adgroup/ the first example ):

```
curl \
-F "name=my ad" \
-F "campaign_id={my_campaign_id}" \
-F "bid_type=CPC" \
-F "bid_info={'CLICKS':110}" \
-F "targeting={'countries':['US']}" \
-F "creative={'creative_id':{my_creative_id}}" \
-F "access_token={my_fb_app_access_token}" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/act_{my_account_id}/adgroups"
```

*the access_token is my whitelisted app token and I have it extended to a long term token. 
When I tried to take off any of the required fields, the error was specific. Ex. if I took of creative, it gave me this error: {"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"The Adgroup Create Failed for the following reason: You must include one of \"max_bid\" or \"bid_info\" fields","code":1487087}}

Does anyone have the same issue and does anyone know if it is just a fb server issue and will fix by itself?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0, this appears to be a `Temporary issue due to downtime - retry the operation after waiting.`. Although [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459594/oauthexception-code-2-for-particular-account-when-using-sessionloginsample) seems to indicate that may not always be completely accurate.